# PHP explicit call to python version

Tags: php, python, bash

My site is hosted on Godaddy, it has python 2.6 installed natively. I figured out I was unable to install python packages with the native python, so I installed python 2.7 in `home`. I am able to SSH in and run 2.7 just fine using python (I set the `PATH` correctly it seems). Also, when I run `python -V` I get `Python 2.7.11`.

When I try and execute the script in a PHP script via a custom plugin, it keeps trying to run 2.6. I've tried changing the shebang but I get permission or invalid directory errors. 2.7 is under `public_html/python/bin`.

How do I get PHP to use 2.7?

I am using this bit of PHP to call the script, which I found on another answer.

```
      echo "<script> function(); </script>";
      $data = shortcode_atts(
          [
              'file' => 'predict.py'
          ],
          $attributes
      );

      $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'] . ' 2>&1', 'r' );
      $read = '';

      while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
      {
          $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
      }

      pclose( $handle );

      return $read;
```

EDIT:
I want to point out I am using Wordpress, and for clarity, in SSH I have changed the default `python` from 2.6 to 2.7 and have even install python3 and can call it fine using `python3`. PHP script in Wordpress plugin has no idea these pythons exist, I'm assuming they are only available to my SSH account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was that the server will not run anything but Python 2.6, I got around this by using SSH2 to run shell commands from PHP.